# Flask redirect ignores base URL with nginx gunicorn

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

A redirect using:

`redirect(url_for('someroute', param=val))`

Is routed to:

`http/someroute/val`

instead of:

`http://site.ip.add.ress/someroute/val`

It works properly on dev (ubuntu + flask built-in server) but doesn't on production (nginx + gunicorn).

I followed [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/) which instructs me to setup the config for nginx as follows:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host http://site.ip.add.ress;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP site.ip.add.ress;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask_project/static/;
    }
}
```

My Flask app is as simple as the common flask hello-world stuff you see in virtually all tutorials online.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the [ProxyFix](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups) middleware on your Flask application?

Comment: No.  Should I be?  My application isn't behind a proxy.  It's on a digitalocean vps.

Comment: nginx is your proxy here. `ProxyFix` use those `proxy_set_header` values to populate the correct environment for Flask.

Comment: I don't have a good handle on this stuff.  I have some reading to do.  Thanks for your help.  All the tutorials reference variables with such as "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for", "$remote_addr", and "$host".  All I have is my one project, on my one VPS, with one IP.  I'll be googling...

Comment: ...it just occured to me, should `proxy_set_header Host http://site.ip.add.ress;` be `proxy_set_header Host $host;` verbatim?  As in, am I supposed to change the string "$host"?

Comment: Usually, you'd use `$host`, but whatever you set there should be forwarded to your Flask application via `ProxyFix`.

Comment: Try add `_external=True` as an argument for `url_for`: `redirect(url_for('someroute', param=val, _external=True))`